# Put UIView fixed on a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm very new in iOS app development and I'm trying to put an uiView fixed on top of uiTableViewController (like an header). But I'm facing difficulties with the swift syntax. Searching for a solution, I found the usage of the function scrollViewDidScroll, like that:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect fixedFrame = self.uiTopView.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.menuViewRelative.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

This does not work due the wrong syntax. So, I did that:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll (scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
    CGRect fixedFrame = self.uiTopView.frame;
    fixedFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.menuViewRelative.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

However I'm getting error on CGRect code line: "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ;". As I said, I'm very new in iOS development, and I can't figure out what is wrong with the syntax. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Yes, there's no need to add 0, but this don't matter, right? So this observation is useless. I'm using swift, and I'm trying to adapt the code.

Comment: No, it won't affect anything functionally. Just trying to help make your code a bit more succinct and readable.

Answer (score 1):

So in Swift you declare a variable with the keywords var or let.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll (scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
   var fixedFrame = self.uiTopView.frame;
   fixedFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
   self.menuViewRelative.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your reply, but I'm getting error yet: "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". I need to study a lot to understand this language :(

Comment: Can you share some more code from your controller to better understand your problem?